# Disable bound click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I try to disable the binded click event in jquery, but I can found only to unbind or off the event click. If I do `unbind()` I can't get back those binded functions back.

For eg: I have a three div binded various function with click event. In some case I dont want particular div click event. So I try to **disable** that event only can't try to unbind() or off() the event. If I unbind() the event from div then again I need to bind those functions back to that div. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/WuNGJ/1/)

Is there a way to disable the event and enable back those events without unbinding it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use a simple flag , upon click dont excute function unless the flag is true !

Comment: @ProllyGeek If I set a flag I declare as a global variable. For eg: If I have a 100 div and everyone has different function. Then I need to initialize 100 different flag for that.

Comment: no i mean just one flag when you want to disable the event , could you give a clear example.

Comment: @ProllyGeek In this question I add a fiddle example. You can set a flag for single event for a single div. How can I handle if I have large number of div's and its event

Comment: when do you want to bind event back again , i understand that you want to unbind events from rest of div if one of them is click , so when should you bind them back ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek That is example only so don't imagine that's a real case. My question is I want to disable the event binded instead of unbinding it. Is there a possible to disable event.

Comment: do you want something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/WuNGJ/2/

Answer (score 2):

You can stop event like this:

```
function handler(e){
    if(yourcondition)
        e.preventDefault();
    else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a class name to those div's. And call the click event though this class name like

```
$(".class_name").click(function(){ });
```

and when you want to disable the click event then use the id selector to remove the class

```
$("#div_id").removeClass("class_name");
```

and when you want to add the click event then then use the id selector to add the class

```
$("#div_id").addClass("class_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

in this example

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/WuNGJ/2/

you can remove class pointer from all elements so that no element will respond to any bound action , once you trun back the class , it will respond normally , class binding and unbining can be done by clicking div 1.

```
$(".element").on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("triggered"))
     {

$(".element").addClass('pointer');
$(this).removeClass("triggered");
}
else if($(this).hasClass("pointer"))
     {

$(".pointer").removeClass("pointer");
$(this).addClass("triggered");
}
//do whatever
})
```